# Mathematical expression for quotient

Tags: functions, notation, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have a $s$ equation as below,

---

$$ s = \frac{y}{(\frac{y}{x+0.5})+1} $$

However the result under $(\frac{y}{x+0.5})$ should be a $\mathbb{N}$ number even result is in decimal, let say the result obtain from $(\frac{y}{x+0.5})$ is 1.892 , then the result that we want should be in integer which in this case is 1 instead of 1.892. Otherwise, the whole equation $ \frac{y}{(\frac{y}{x+0.5})+1} $ will produce wrong result for our solution.

How to remove the decimal point from the result of $(\frac{y}{x+0,5})$ or is there any mathematical expression that we only stated the result should be in quotient which in $\mathbb{N}$ number and remove the decimal point value.

Comment: The phrases "greatest integer function" or "floor function" may prove useful in your Google-aided research.  Though I am not sure that I see the connection to [tag:linear-algebra], and the tag [tag:natural-numbers] seems misapplied.

Comment: Thanks @XanderHenderson will research the suggested phrase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

$$ s = \frac{y}{\left\lfloor\frac{y}{x+0.5}\right\rfloor+1} $$